# passing mixed keyword non keyword arguments programmatically to a bound method in Python

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing

I have an object.

```
class myClass:
   def f1(self,arg1,param1,dictionary_settings={}):
   # stuff
   def f2(self,arg1,dictionary_settings={}):
   # stuff
myobj=myClass()
```

I am now trying to use this object from another class.
I need to call programmatically f1 or f2, and inject parameters accordingly.
I can do that with getattr:

```
f_to_call=getattr(myobj,'f1')
```

How do I then pass my arguments which may be keyword and non-keyword arguments?

Comment: Not related, but f1 and f2 are instance methods so they need to take `self` as the first argument; and, you should not set a dictionary as a default, since that exposes you to the mutable default argument gotcha.

Comment: thanks!  I have corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `f = getattr(myobj,'f1')` just makes `f` a bound method. Passing the parameters happens just like in any other method.

```
f(1, 2, a=3, b=4)
```

or,

```
positional = [1, 2]
keyword = {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
f(*positional, **keyword)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
class myClass:
    @staticmethod
    def f1(arg1, param1, dictionary_settings={}):
        print(arg1, param1, dictionary_settings)

    @staticmethod
    def f2(arg1, _=None, dictionary_settings={}):
        print(arg1, dictionary_settings)

myobj=myClass()

f_to_call = myobj.f1
f_to_call(1, 2)

f_to_call = myobj.f2
f_to_call(1, 2)
f_to_call(1)
```

Doing this, we have the benefit of using `f2` as both:

1. `f2(arg1, irrelevant, dictionary_settings=dictionary_settings)` and
2. `f2(arg1, dictionary_settings=dictionary_settings)`

Answer (score 1):

In this way first you have to declare those method as static method

```
class myClass:
    @staticmethod
    def f1(arg1,param1,dictionary_settings={}):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def f2(arg1,dictionary_settings={}):
        pass
```

Then you can only call them as you wants in your question

```
myobj=myClass()
f = getattr(myobj,'f1')
```

then you can call them by passing first positional argument and then keyword like

```
f(1,2,4)
# or 
f(1,2,{})
# or
f(1,2,dictionary_settings={'a':1})
```